# flexjson.JSONException Don't know how to bind

Tags: java, android, json, flexjson

My android application use flexjson library to deserialize json data string received from server via RESTfull webservice. But when deserialize i get error.

> flexjson.JSONException: [ data.status ]: Don't know how to bind Clock_in into class wfa.com.tma.wfa.type.TimeClockStatus.  You might need to use an ObjectFactory instead of a plain class.

this is my String

```
{
  "data":
     {
       "todayShift":
           {
              "startTime":"1970-01-01T13:30:00Z",
              "endTime":"1970-01-02T00:00:00Z",
              "office":
                    {
                       "id":1,"name":"Location Test 1"
                    }
          },
       "currentTime":"2017-10-12T07:47:11Z",
       "status":"Clock_in",
       "latestTime":"2017-10-12T07:46:13Z",
       "latestOffice":{"id":1,"name":"Location Test 1"}},
       "meta":{"type":"TimeClockDto"}
 }
```

the DTO of this String

```
public class TimeClockDto implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private TodayShiftDto todayShift;
    private String currentTime;
    private TimeClockStatus status;
    private String latestTime;
    private BaseLocationDto latestOffice;
    public TimeClockDto(TodayShiftDto todayShift, String currentTime, 
    TimeClockStatus status, String latestClockInTime,
                        BaseLocationDto latestOffice)
    {
        this.todayShift = todayShift;
        this.currentTime = currentTime;
        this.status = status;
        this.latestTime = latestClockInTime;
        this.latestOffice = latestOffice;
    }
    //getter, setter
}
```

`and the deserialize code

and the enum class

```
public enum TimeClockStatus
{
Clock_in, Clock_out;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve this problem by using `EnumObjectFactory`

```
TimeClockDto result = new JSONDeserializer<TimeClockDto>
                        .use("data", TimeClockDto.class)
                        .use("data.todayShift", TodayShiftDto.class)
                        .use("data.status", new EnumObjectFactory())
                        .use("data.latestOffice", BaseLocationDto.class)
                        .deserialize(param.getResult(),TimeClockDto.class);
```